# Help with a "magnet block" probability problem

Tags: probability

The question is as the following, and I get really confused by the hint.

> 7. A total of $n$ bar magnets are placed end to end in a line with random independent orientation. Adjacent like poles repel, ends with opposite polarities joint to form blocks. Let $X$ be the number of blocks of joined magnets. Find $E(X)$ and $(X)$. *Hint:* Show that $X=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}I_i$, where $I_i$ is the indicator function that the $i$th pair has opposite polarity.

For example, suppose we have 4 magnets A,B,C,D and the have the combination
-A+ -B+ -C+ -D+,
then every pair in this combination has opposite polarity, and I think the four magnet bars will form one block (one block consists of all A,B,C,D)? Then isn't it $X=1$ and $1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}I_i=4$?

I probably misunderstood the question or hint. Thank you.

Comment: $i^{th}$ pair has opposite polarity mean either (+-  -+) or (-+  +-).

Comment: @MickA Thanks for reply. Isn't a pair with opposite adjacent polarities join together?

Comment: Read Mick's comment again - the polarity refers to the orientation of the entire bar.

Comment: If you have +- next to -+ (opposite polarity) they will repel.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I see. But I think "$i$th pair with opposite orientation" could be less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The number of blocks is equal to 1 plus the number of gaps.

A gap forms when a magnet and its successor have opposite *orientation*.   (They worded this badly.   This is what they meant by "polarity".)

Hence : $X= 1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} I_k$ where $I_k$ is the indicator that magnet numbers $k$ and $k+1$ have opposing orientations.